# Windows SYSTEMTIME structure different then System clock?

Tags: winapi, time, rust

The goal of the following code is to call the Win32 function `FileTimeToSystemTime`:

```
pub fn convert_times(s: SystemTime) -> Option<SYSTEMTIME> {
    let mut st = SYSTEMTIME::default();
    let x: u64 = unsafe { transmute(s) };
    let low = (x & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF) as u32;
    let high = ((x & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32) as u32;
    let fs = FILETIME {
        dwLowDateTime: low,
        dwHighDateTime: high,
    };
    if unsafe { FileTimeToSystemTime(transmute(&fs), transmute(&mut st)) } > 0 {
        Some(st)
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

When I take a known file time `131147233180069965` which was generated at `2016-08-03T14:41 US-EST(GMT+5)` according to my computer's clock. The return structure I get from this returns `2016-0803T18:41:58.006`

This is +4 hours.

While US-EST is GMT+5?

Is it because Daylight Saving Time is -1hr?

Comment: Yes, August is during DST, so the current time zone is EDT (GMT-4), not EST (GMT-5). If you need to know local time from a `SYSTEMTIME` that uses UTC, use `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime()` (or convert the result to a Rust-native time format).

Comment: Or, simply don't deal with timestamps in local timezones to begin with.  Deal with UTC/GMT timestamps instead. `FILETIME` and `SYSTEMTIME` are usually expressed in UTC by default, you usually have to take extra steps to convert them to local time (`FileTimeToLocalFileTime()`, `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime()`, `GetLocalTime()`, etc). Try to work with UTC when possible.

Comment: Yes I understand where you are coming from, and yes you correct. Working in UTC is better for everyone. I was just wondering why the call was behaving weird. I'm just trying to build a library to wrap these functions, not offering the functionality that is already including in windows would be dumb.

Comment: Does Rust have a time library of its own? Before I add an answer.

Comment: Yes/No. Rust has it's own time library but it's based on strftime, and Tm structure in POSIX not those in Windows. In both Rust/Unix it exposes the `SystemTime` structure although they have different meanings in different OS's. Furthermore there is no way to convert a `SystemTime` value into a wall clock value in Unix or Windows. Nor is their an external library to handle this.

Comment: So it's just a thin wrapper around C's `<time.h>`?! That's very weird :S I'll post the answer I was going to write later then; thanks for the info (which I was going to use to write it).

Comment: @andlabs I think you are looking for [chrono](https://github.com/lifthrasiir/rust-chrono).

Comment: chrono doesn't offer a function that accepts `SystemTime` as an argument. Rust's STL will give a `SystemTime` when I interact with an OS, but I'm having to write the library that'll convert the `SystemTime` to a native time.

Answer (score 0):

`FileTimeToLocalFileTime()` returns time at UTC. In the United States, locations normally in EST transition to EDT during Daylight Saving Time, so it will be GMT+5 DST-1 or UTC-4.

To get time in the local timezone and take DST into account, one would instead need to call `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime()`.

Generally this inadvisable as working in UTC is preferable for computers as 2 intercommunicating computers are not necessarily in the same timezone.